# How to create a custom FileUpload in XWiki with progress bar using FileUploadPlugin

Tags: java, file-upload, progress-bar, xwiki

Anyone has any ideas or piece of codes (it's better) about how to create a custome FileUpload in XWiki with progress bar using `FileUploadPlugin`?

What I want exactly is how to get instantly the progress data from XWiki server side ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not currently possible with this approach, the serverside part doesn't expose any progress API.

However, if you're interested in displaying upload progress in a browser, this has [already been implemented](http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-8132) very recently (4.2 Milestone 3). The idea is that the browser already tracks the progress of the upload, and it regularly fires JavaScript events. But this only works in modern browsers that implement the [XMLHttpRequest version 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), which is [almost every browser](http://caniuse.com/xhr2) except Internet Explorer 9 and lower (IE10 does implement it).

If, however, you do want to implement your own serverside progress component, then you have to modify the [FileUploadPlugin](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/70d4e7522e2cfc86c67305fa398d939cadce78de/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/plugin/fileupload/FileUploadPlugin.java#L245) to add a custom progress listener, which is already supported by the Apache commons-fileupload library that is used internally. How you use that progress listener depends on what you want to do with the progress events.

Comment: The referenced FileUploadPlugin code is labelled as deprecated. Would you recommend a different approach now?

Comment: The whole concept of plugins has been deprecated in XWiki for many years, to be replaced by modular components, but existing plugins are taking a long time to be replaced. You can still use the `FileUploadPlugin` if you want, but it would be better to [replace it with a component](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/DevGuide/WritingComponents) for your needs.